# Run code when Android app starts and exists

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In my app I need to call code whenever the app closes (pauses) and then run code again whenever the app starts again (resumes).  For example, I call a web service that syncs the data whenever the app starts or exits.  This is easy in iOS because of the central app resume and suspend methods.

I understand the OnPause and OnResume in the Activity, however, is there a central way to handle this?  The user could leave the app on Activity3 and come back later, or be in another screen, etc.  I'd hate to have to have the same code in every Activity's OnPause and OnResume to handle the "app" startup and shutdown code routines.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: You do not need this. You wouldn't do this in a Web app, for example, because there is no concept in a Web app of the "app closes" or the "app starts again". An Android application is much like a Web app in this regard. Activities are designed to come and go, each operating largely independently of the others, just like Web pages of a Web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a common Activity which just handles onResume() and onPause() in a certain way and then make every Activity extend from that one instead of Activity directly.

Comment: This concept is good except that the onResume would run when every activity is resumed so I couldn't "sync on start" once per use of the application.  I don't want to run this code every time an activity is resumed.  I may have to remove this feature as it doesn't lend well to the Android app like it works on the iPhone app.

Comment: Well, then put the "sync on start" code on the first Activity, you call super.onResume() anyway and there the common code is executed. Only the common behavior must be putted there, you can place particular actions on any subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider subclassing Activty, have each of your activities extend that and just do what you need to when any of them pause or resume.

You could use some static members in an Application class that your new activity base uses to track state or store whatever you need.

Also, Application class has an onCreate() method which will run each time the application is started. There is no pause or resume for Application, however.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a main Activity that is extended by all your other activities and override the onPause and onResume.

But the problem you will face if you want to extend another Activity class such as a ListActivity.

Another approach is to create a new class that extends application and override its onCreate and create a static method that acts as onPause and manually call it by each of your activities